# Access to a Dapp on a private network from mobile

Tags: private-blockchain, dapp-development, dapps, web3-providers

Is it possible to speak with a Dapp (or with a smart contract) stored on my private network from mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Read data**

If you want to read data (call a constant method to read a state), you can do it from any mobile browser (like Chrome).

You first need to connect to a node

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(PRIVATE_NODE_RPC_ENDPOINT));
```

and then make a smart contract [as explained here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods)

```
// contract abi
var abi = [{
     name: 'myConstantMethod',
     type: 'function',
     constant: true,
     inputs: [{ name: 'a', type: 'string' }],
     outputs: [{name: 'd', type: 'string' }]
}, {
     name: 'myStateChangingMethod',
     type: 'function',
     constant: false,
     inputs: [{ name: 'a', type: 'string' }, { name: 'b', type: 'int' }],
     outputs: []
}, {
     name: 'myEvent',
     type: 'event',
     inputs: [{name: 'a', type: 'int', indexed: true},{name: 'b', type: 'bool', indexed: false}]
}];

// creation of contract object
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);

// initiate contract for an address
var myContractInstance = MyContract.at('0xc4abd0339eb8d57087278718986382264244252f');

// call constant function
var result = myContractInstance.myConstantMethod('myParam');
console.log(result) // '0x25434534534'
```

**Write data**

However, if you want to write data, you need to send a transaction which means you need a private key (basically a wallet).

There are a few Ethereum Mobile browsers on the market like Status, Toshi or Cipher. I just checked and no one accepts yet to connect to a private node via RPC (only public networks like mainet, ropsten, rinkeby). You will need to wait the feature to be implemented on one of those or a new Ethereum mobile wallet with this feature.